# How can I get co ordinates(x,y values) of tracked object in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to track pupil iris by using open cv in c++.
I want coordinates of tracked pupil iris. How can I get it?
Right now I can tracked pupil iris, but I want coordinates as output in numbers. Which function can make this happen?

The code I've written until now is this:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360);

    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    namedWindow("Video",1);
    Mat src_gray;

    while(1) {

        Mat frame,grey,edge,draw,src_gray;
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor( frame, grey, CV_BGR2GRAY );   // get a new frame from   camera
        Canny( grey, edge, 50, 150, 3);
        edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);
        GaussianBlur( edge, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
        vector<Vec3f> circles;
        HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2,   src_gray.rows/16, 80, 100, 30, 50 );

        /// Draw the circles detected
        for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ ) {
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
            // circle center
            circle( src_gray, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
            // circle outline
            circle( src_gray, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
        }

        Rect Rec(370,100,200,150);
        rectangle(src_gray,Rec,Scalar(255),1,8,0);
        namedWindow("roi",640*360);
        Mat Roi=src_gray(Rec);
        imshow("roi",Roi);
        imshow("Video", src_gray);

        // Press 'c' to escape
        if(waitKey(30) == 'c') break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isn't your `center` variable in `circles` loop the coordinates you are looking for?

Comment: yeah...you're right..thanks :)